# AutoMapper: Int to String and back again

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper

EDIT: to include TypeConverter

To set the stage, I am stripping out code from a existing WCF service to put into a business object (BO) that will be referenced by the WCF to provide clients with information.  A requirement is to make the employeeId of an Employee object to be an integer rather than the string currently used.  I'm using AutoMapper to map all of the objects between the BO and WCF so that contracts do not break.  However I'm struggling with how to provide the mapping back and forth for the EmployeeId to be an integer in BO and still contractually serve strings via the WCF.

BO

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ......
}
```

WCF

```
[DataContract(Name = "Employee", Namespace="url")]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Id {get; set;}
    ......
}
```

Mapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee.Entity.Employee, Employee.Service.Entity.Employee>()
```

PaddedStringTypeConverter class:

```
public class PaddedStringTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<int, string>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var sourceValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(context.SourceValue);
        return sourceValue.ToString("D9");
    }
}
```

I've seen that I could use Custom Type Converters in AutoMapper to change the BO from an integer to our fixed length of nine characters so that an integer value of 4610 would be equivalent to a string of "000004610".  However, how do I get it back to an integer value.

How would you do this?

Comment: Can't you just make another type converter to do the string to int conversion?  Int32.Parse() would parse your string correctly.  Perhaps I'm not understanding your question though.

Comment: I could probably add for that mapping:

  ConvertUsing(Convert.ToInt32)

I'm unsure how to add it and my TypeConverter to the CreateMap so that only with this object are the types converted.

Comment: I should add that I only want the Id property rather than all ints and strings in the Employee object to change.

Answer (score 8):

Create two mappings for both directions:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee.Entity.Employee, Employee.Service.Entity.Employee>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString("D9")))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src)));
```

This creates maps in both directions and the options convert the types for that member back and forth.

ReverseMap is a shortcut for CreateMap with the source/destination types switched.

Comment: Jimmy thanks, however I need to do it only for the EmployeeId in the Employee class.

Comment: Updated to be type map-specific

Comment: Very nice!  I had not seen ReverseMap yet. I'll implement it soon and check back to mark as an answer.  I got side railed onto another project that will be taking some time for a week or two.

Comment: By the way, Employee.Entity.Employee has some sub-classing associated with it.  I'll be using the '.Include' in my CreateMap declaration.  Does it matter where those includes need to be placed?  Such as before the '.ReverseMap' or after.  Or do I also include the includes reversed after '.ReverseMap'.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You'd need the includes in both places if both have base classes you want to inherit mapping behavior from.

Answer (score 2):

Automapper is great for automatically mapping to/from things with the same name.  If you want to change the conversion, or if the name of the thing you want to map to is different you need to use the .ForMember().  Your map would be something like this:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Employee.Entity.Employee, Employee.Service.Entity.Employee>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeID, expression => expression.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToInt32(src.EmployeeID)))
;
```

Then add the reverse custom mapping as well.

You shouldn't need you PaddedStringTypeConverter class.

Comment: jhilden, thanks this helps some. Are you familiar with the ForSourceMember?  Would this help me with the reverse?